# Analytic continuation of a Dirichlet series with several complex variables

Tags: analytic-number-theory, several-complex-variables, dirichlet-series

For $w_1,w_2,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\operatorname{Re}(w_1)>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(w_2)>0$, define
\begin{equation*}
U(w_1,w_2;z_1,z_2):=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{e^{z_1}}{p^{1+w_1}}-\frac{e^{z_2}}{p^{1+w_2}}+\frac{e^{z_1+z_2}}{p^{1+w_1+w_2}}\right),
\end{equation*}
given by the series
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n_1,n_2=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n_1)e^{z_1\omega(n_1)}\mu(n_2)e^{z_2\omega(n_2)}}{[n_1,n_2]\cdot n_1^{w_1}n_2^{w_2}},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation}
V(w_1,w_2;z_1,z_2):=\zeta(1+w_1)^{-e^{z_1}}\zeta(1+w_2)^{-e^{z_2}}\zeta(1+w_1+w_2)^{e^{z_1+z_2}}.
\end{equation}
The claim is that the ratio $\tilde{U}:=U/V$ extends to a holomorphic function for $w_1,w_2,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\operatorname{Re}(w_1)>-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\operatorname{Re}(w_2)>-\frac{1}{2}$. This seems plausible, but I'm not sure I fully understand (my knowledge of several complex variables is limited). Does anyone have a good explanation?